# Pythonic code style

Tags: python, coding-style, readability, pep8

I am an amateur programmer writing some python for a research project at my university. I need my code to be very readable for anyone who may be working on this project after me, and as such I am trying to follow PEP 8. I have run into a conflict of rules however. The offending lines are a dictionary definition after a long string of for loops and if statements. The problem is that convention has it that no line should be longer than 79 characters, yet line continuations should be indented from where they started from. I see three options of what could logically be done, but am unsure of what is best.

option 1: leave offending lines too long

```
def getIndexedData(directory):                                                 |
    ...                                                                        |
    ...                                                                        |
    ...                                                                        |
                        # construct dictionary of images with peak locations   |
                        peaks[image] = {                                       |
                            'Xpixel': [float(x) for x in step[17][10][0].text.s|plit(' ')],
                            'Ypixel': [float(x) for x in step[17][10][1].text.s|plit(' ')]}
    return peaks                                                               |
```

option 2: unindent continued lines

```
def getIndexedData(directory):                                                 |
    ...                                                                        |
    ...                                                                        |
    ...                                                                        |
                        # construct dictionary of images with peak locations   |
                        peaks[image] = {                                       |
                'Xpixel': [float(x) for x in step[17][10][0].text.split(' ')], |
                'Ypixel': [float(x) for x in step[17][10][1].text.split(' ')]} |
    return peaks                                                               |
```

option 3: split definitions somewhere (not sure where)

```
def getIndexedData(directory):                                                 |
    ...                                                                        |
    ...                                                                        |
    ...                                                                        |
                        # construct dictionary of images with peak locations   |
                        peaks[image] = {                                       |
                            'Xpixel':                                          |
                           [float(x) for x in step[17][10][0].text.split(' ')],|
                            'Ypixel':                                          |
                           [float(x) for x in step[17][10][1].text.split(' ')]}|
    return peaks                                                               |
```

I am also open to any other suggestions :)

Thanks,

~Aaron

Comment: There is a code review stack exchange that you may wish to post this in instead of here.

Comment: The best option may very well be "4: refactor so you don't have that many levels of indentation".

Comment: If I remember correctly PEP 8 suggests 120 characters. 80 is very very strict, some would say obsolete. As for your question - I would go with the second option - but my opinion is as good as any. Just go with what you feel is best. That's definitely not going to make your code un-readable. Second, remember that PEP8 is just guidelines - sometimes you have exceptions...

Comment: @Wooble not always possible, for example, when you have a few long URLs.

Comment: I can definitely move this to code review if it would be better suited there. I am not terribly familiar with the site yet.

Comment: @alfasin: it says 79, with an additional proviso that 100 is ok if you can get the entire team working on the code to agree. 120 is right out.

Comment: actually, maybe I can't...
how does one move a question to a different board?

Comment: @Aaron, copy all the text from here, delete the question, then post it to code review

Comment: You can flag for a moderator and request migration; codereview's not a valid migration target for non-mods yet. (Although codereview will want to see more of your code, to review it, probably.)

Comment: In either case, you guys have been very helpful. I think whoever comes after me can stand looking at more than 79 characters per line for a few lines. It looks better that way in my opinion unless the text wraps.

Comment: Another option: `'Xpixel': map(float, step[17][10][0].text.split(' '))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of relevent snippets from [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) with my italics added.

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide
>   is important. Consistency within a project is more important.
>   Consistency within one module or function is most important.
>
> But most importantly: *know when to be inconsistent* -- sometimes the
>   style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment.
>   Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate
>   to ask!
>
> ... *it is okay to increase the nominal line length* from 80 to 100
>   characters (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99
>   characters), provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped
>   at 72 characters.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. I'll definitely try out some of your suggestions to try and make the dict generation more concise, but for the time being, the code will likely stand as the first option that I described.

Answer (score 3):

Functions are best when they are short and sweet. By that I mean they should when possible have a very clearly defined and simple purpose. If a function has many levels of indentiation, it is a signal that the function is trying to do too much. Some portion of it can probably be refactored as a function unto itself.

One advantage of having "small" functions is that it makes code easier to understand. It also makes code easier to unit test. And finally, it helps keep code under the 79 column PEP8 style limit.

However, another trick you can use to keep the code inside the 79-column limit is to use temporary variables:

```
def getIndexedData(directory):                                                 
    ...                                                                        
    ...                                                                        
    ...                                                                        
                        # construct dictionary of images with peak locations
                        texts = [text.split(' ') for text in step[17][10][:2]]
                        x, y = [map(float, text) for text in texts]
                        peaks[image] = {'Xpixel': x, 'Ypixel': y}
    return peaks
```

Comment: wouldnt `texts` make more sense as a generator so you only iterate it once? (+1 all the same)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I doubt it would make much difference.  Generators do a good job of keeping memory consumption down, but I don't think they do much for performance here (and may even slow things down).

Comment: depends on list size I think ... but you are right here it would almost certainly not help... i didnt notice it was only 2 elements long ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I did a little timeit testing; it appears in this case there is a trade-off between space and speed. The list comprehension appears to be faster (for moderate sized lists -- probably as long as you don't hit swap space), while the generator saves memory.

Comment: @unutbu I definitely agree that smaller functions look nicer and are easier to read. I'll be sure to save your code to try out later.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I am relatively new to python and general purpose programming, and don't have a full grasp yet of generators. It's definitely something I need to read up on.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the number of nested for-loops and if-statements. Use functions, generators or filters to achieve this. If you show more of your code, we can help.
You also can split the list-generation to a separate line:

```
xpixel = step[17][10][0].text.split(' ')
ypixel = step[17][10][1].text.split(' ')
peaks[image] = {
    'Xpixel': map(float, xpixel),
    'Ypixel': map(float, ypixel),
}
```

You can also write a convert function:

```
def str_to_floats(text):
  return [float(x) for x in text.split()]

...

peaks[image] = {
    'Xpixel': str_to_floats(step[17][10][0].text),
    'Ypixel': str_to_floats(step[17][10][1].text),
}
```

Btw. `step[17][10][0].text` looks strange to me. Of your examples, only option 1 looks readable for me.

Comment: step[...][..] comes from a eTree object from a parsed .xml file that is several hundred megabytes. There may be a more efficient way of crawling through the data structure, but this seems to work relatively fast and it gets the job done.